# Can i trigger a Load() function with a scroll() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that load a php file when I click in the button.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('#loaded').on('click', function(){
      $("#phpContent").load('beach.php');
});
```

this work fine and the load() function give me the file, the problems is that when I change the onClick function to a Scroll function, the line

> $("#phpContent").load('beach.php');

is no longer call or doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $('body').scroll(function(){
     $("#phpContent").load('beach.php');
});
```

so the Load() function can't be call with that method? or I'm doing something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace in both examples. As far as the scroll part goes, I'm pretty sure that is going to fire off a bunch of times as you scroll. You might want to trigger only at a specified scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works even for this SO page:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        $("#phpContent").load('beach.php');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event for the global container is fired on `window`, not on the body element itself, so you need to listen to it on the right object.

Next, as can be seen in the following snippet, this call will fire many times.

```js
const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&format=html';
$(window).scroll(event => $("#target").load(url));
```

```css
body { height: 200vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Assuming that you only want this to fire the first time the page is scrolled, you can use `jQuery.one`, which will only fire once.

```js
const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&format=html';
$(window).one('scroll', event => $("#target").load(url));
```

```css
body { height: 200vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Oh i see, with the previous answers i could trigger the call of the event setting a specified position, what you are saying is indee a problem because the event trigger a lot of times. So the Jquery.one might be very useful i'll give it a try